# MySQL get rest of values

Tags: mysql, sql

Using this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(job_primary.id) AS id 
FROM `job_primary` 
LEFT JOIN `job_skill` ON `job_skill`.`job_id` = `job_primary`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `job_facts` ON `job_facts`.`job_id` = `job_primary`.`id`  
LEFT JOIN `job_location` ON `job_location`.`job_id` = `job_primary`.`id`  
LEFT JOIN `job_people` ON `job_people`.`job_id` = `job_primary`.`id`   
LEFT JOIN `job_sec` ON `job_sec`.`job_id` = `job_primary`.`id` 
                    AND job_sec.exp_start_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() 
INNER JOIN `user_skills` ON `user_skills`.`skill_id` = `job_skill`.`skill_id` 
                         AND user_skills.user_id = 1 
WHERE job_primary.posted_by != 1
```

I am getting only the id value. But I want to get the rest of the values with distinct id. Don't think about rest of the codes. The problem is here, if I use:

```
select *, job_primary.id as id
```

to select code then I get all data. But it is not distinct. So if I used

```
SELECT *, distinct(job_primary.id) as id
```

or

```
SELECT distinct(job_primary.id), * as id
```

but it is showing errors.

Comment: `but it's showing errors.` **What errors?**

Comment: For future code: You don't need to quote/backtick your column & table names.  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a name that is a reserved word, or you have embedded spaces or punctuation in them, and those are terrible practices to avoid anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confussion is what to query itself, nixon1333. What do you want to ask to the database? If you want just one row per id, group'em by with `SELECT * FROM ... GROUP BY job_primary.id`